# Unable to add bluetooth device to Lenovo T440 laptop running Windows 8.1

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, bluetooth

I recently got a new laptop at work that I want to pair with my Galaxy S5 via bluetooth. The laptop has bluetooth turned on (PC Settings -> PC and devices -> Bluetooth: On). The laptop is also set to 'discoverable'. The phone is also set to 'discoverable' and sees the laptop. When I submit a pairing request from the phone, the phone displays the key but the laptop doesn't detect any incoming request.

When I go on PC Settings -> PC and devices -> Devices, the laptop does not show the phone as device. The button "Add a device" doesn't do anything as in "the laptop doesn't scan or open a window or provide any sort of results".

Lastly, when I navigate to Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Devices and Printers and click on "Add a device" a blank window briefly opens and immediately closes. I would expect that window to contain the set-up wizard. The window has neither title text nor any other contents. There is no error message.

Anyone have any idea how to get this fixed? I'm out of ideas :( It's not the phone as my girlfriend's phone results in the same situation.

Any help is MUCH appreciated! I've spent days trying to figure this out...

Comment: Try to reinstall your bluetooth drivers. Get the latest drivers from the vendor (this is NOT lenovo).

Comment: Thank you for your response. The vendor is Intel. I had tried that twice already, I missed putting that in the text. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer is very simple (according to our IT guy).
Start -> Services -> Device Association Service -> Enable (automatic)

Magic is done.